# No se me muestra la imagen en JTable

Tags: java, java-swing, imagen, jtable

Muy buenas, el problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un **JTable** donde hay 4 Columnas la ultima es donde quiero meter el `.gif` y no se muy bien como hacerlo, las imágenes las tengo en local pero la dirección la cojo desde la base de datos con una consulta. Este es el diseño de mi **TableModel:**

```
public class TableModelCoches implements TableModel{

public ArrayList<Coche> coches;

public TableModelCoches(ArrayList<Coche> _coches) {
    this.coches = _coches;
}

@Override
public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0){
    case 0:
        return String.class;
    case 1:
        return float.class;
    case 2:
        return float.class;
    case 3:
        return ImageIcon.class;
    default:
        return String.class;

    }
}


@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}


@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (columnIndex){
    case 0:
        return "Modelo";
    case 1:
        return "Consumo";
    case 2:
        return "Emisiones";
    case 3:
        return "Clasificacion energetica";
    default:
        return "";

    }
}

@Override
/**
 * CANTIDAD DE FILAS
 */
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return coches.size();
}



@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Coche c = coches.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex){
    case 0:
        return c.getnModelo();
    case 1:
        return c.getConsumo();
    case 2:
        return c.getEmisiones();
    case 3:
        return c.getClasificacion();
    default:
        return null;

    }

}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Aquí estaría mi clase de Coche:**

```
public class Coche {

  private String nModelo;
  private String nMarca;
  private float consumo;
  private float emisiones;
  private String clasEnerg;
  private ImageIcon clasificacion;



public Coche(String nModelo, float consumo, float emisiones, ImageIcon clasificacion) {
    super();
    this.nModelo = nModelo;
    this.consumo = consumo;
    this.emisiones = emisiones;
    this.clasificacion = clasificacion;
}

public String getnModelo() {
    return nModelo;
}

public void setnModelo(String nModelo) {
    this.nModelo = nModelo;
}

public String getnMarca() {
    return nMarca;
}

public void setnMarca(String nMarca) {
    this.nMarca = nMarca;
}

public float getConsumo() {
    return consumo;
}

public void setConsumo(float consumo) {
    this.consumo = consumo;
}

public float getEmisiones() {
    return emisiones;
}

public void setEmisiones(float emisiones) {
    this.emisiones = emisiones;
}



public ImageIcon getClasificacion() {
    return clasificacion;
}

public void setClasificacion(ImageIcon clasificacion) {
    this.clasificacion = clasificacion;
 }

}
```

Y por ultimo el método en la parte de persistencia donde recojo la consulta del .gif

```
        case 5:

            sql = 
            "select mo.MODELO, mo.CONSUMO, mo.EMISIONES, efi.icono "
                    + "from modelos mo, eficiencias efi where mo.c_energetica=efi.c_energetica"
                    + " and efi.c_energetica like '" + clasEnerg
                    + "';";
            establecerConexion();
            st = conexion.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            while(rs.next()){


                ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("/assets/iconosclasificacionenergetica/" + rs.getString(4));

                coches.add(new Coche(rs.getString(1), rs.getFloat(2), rs.getFloat(3), icono));

                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

            }

            cerrarConexion();               


            break;
```

La dirección me la recoge bien de la base de datos ya que he hecho la prueba imprimiendolo en la consola.

No me lanza ningún error la aplicación simplemente que esa columna se me queda vacía ya que no muestra la imagen.

Comment: Haz una cosa. Antes de colocarlo en la jtable verifica que puedas ver la imagen. Me refiero a que se cargo bien. Utiliza una ventana emergente para eso. En cuanto a la tabla, configura esa columna para que acepte JLabel y coloca a cada label la imagen como fondo.

Comment: Si carga perfectamente la imagen, la cosa es como hago lo del JLabel, desde la parte de la clase del TableModel y añadirle esa ruta desde ahi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTable/Insert_Image_into_JTable.htm